# flask peewee REST api authentication to limit GET

Tags: python, rest, flask, peewee

I am using flask-peewee to build a new project. Also I am using the REST interface that is included in flask peewee. I followed the example here http://flask-peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#exposing-content-using-a-rest-api and http://flask-peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/rest-api.html#rest-api
 so I ws able to get my rest api up and running including adding the Auth to Rest.

However my problem is I am not able to secure the GET request. I have so far browsed through the source code for rest.py https://github.com/coleifer/flask-peewee/blob/master/flask_peewee/rest.py but not able to find where this is coming from though I did find a lot of good stuff I can use later.

It seems by default the REST API only secure the POST/PUT/DELETE but not GET.

I don't want to make a hack of using flask url secure, I was hoping the flask peewee has some inbuilt method for this. Or if this is a known limitation then what is a good way to handle this

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry you had trouble finding this information.  You can specify a list of HTTP verbs to require authentication on when instantiating your auth class:

```
# when instantiating your authentication
api_auth = UserAuth(auth, protected_methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
read_only_auth = UserAuth(auth) # default protected methods are POST/PUT/DELETE
```

Here is a link to the docs:

http://flask-peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#authenticating-requests-to-the-api

Comment: thank you so much. This is a great flask blueprint. Sorry to have missed the thing in the docs. Where can I get more help from you if you have the time. I need some direction on writing custom auth.

Comment: hit me up in #peewee on irc.freenode.net or contact me through my website (charlesleifer.com) -- happy to help!